# Rest client post with username and password

Tags: ruby, curl, ruby-on-rails-5, rest-client

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://example.com/token/grant \
  --header 'password: password' \
  --header 'username: user' \
  --data '{"app_key":"my_app_key","app_secret":"my_app_secret"}'
```

I am trying to get an equivalent ruby code for the above curl request with rest client.

I have tried:

```
auth = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode64( "#{AA['user_name']}:#{AA['password']}" ).chomp
response = RestClient.post'https://example.com/token/grant', {"app_key":"my_app_key","app_secret":"my_app_secret"}, {  'Authorization' => auth , :accept => :json, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
response = JSON.parse(response)
```

It did not work.

2nd try:

```
RestClient.post 'https://example.com/token/grant', {"app_key":"my_app_key","app_secret":"my_app_secret"}.to_json,  {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password', content_type: 'application/json'}
```

Also did not work.
I have checked username and password is correct.

> It showing that username is missing in the header.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you control the target service (example.com in your example)?

Comment: In the curl command you used you specified `username`/`password` as seperate, independent headers. In your Ruby code, you compiled both into a Basic auth string and pass that as the `Authorization` header. That's obviously a difference. I suggest to drop the `Authorization` and just pass instead: `{ 'username' => user_name , 'password' => password, :accept => :json, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }`

Comment: @TobiasK. I have tried its still giving me that username is missing in the header.

Comment: @thesecretmaster, No I do not have control over it.

Answer (score 1):

As per the description it seems like when running the request using RestClient the header is action is unable to process the header (username since it is the first key in the header hash).

I have executed the below command on a custom code and it worked.

```
 RestClient.post 'https://example.com/token/grant', {"app_key":"my_app_key","app_secret":"my_app_secret"}.to_json,  {username: 'username', password: 'password', content_type: 'application/json'}
```

Note: I have just updated the representation of header keys passed in the header hash.

Comment: Still same issue. Username is missing in the header.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with Rest client. It did not work. Then I also tried Faraday, Net HTTP nothing works.

Then I have tried with [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb). It works.

```
require 'curb'
request_path= 'https://example.com/token/grant'
payload = {
          app_key: 'app_key',
          app_secret: 'app_secret'
        }
http = Curl.post(request_path, payload.to_json) do |http|
          http.headers['username'] = 'user_name'
          http.headers['password'] = 'password'
          http.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        end
JSON.parse(http.body_str)
```